# $head variable - blank page after clearing caches (Clarified)

Tags: theming

When I clear the caches I get a blank page because the page stops rendering after the $head variable in my html.tpl.php. This is then in the source at that point:

```
<script />
```

The rest of the page is there in the source after this tag; the page just doesn't show. If I add an ending `</script>` tag after $head, then the script is closed and the rest of the page prints out.

Any ideas? I just did not know what to search for.

EDIT: I did want to mention that I recently updated the site to 7.41 from 7.39 and also deleted some fields from a content type. Unfortunately, I do not know when this problem emerged in relation to these changes.